Runtime errors when using vectors of large sizes
This is based off of a problem on Kattis called Galactic Collegiate Programming Contest. I tried to make a solution in C++, and it works for smaller numbers such as their test input of:
3 4
2 7
3 5
1 6
1 9

But as soon as I introduce the larger numbers they give, the program suddenly gets stuck at runtime and doesn't produce any output. In the code I'm including, I also have the test cases set up for these large numbers. Is there some sort of memory leak, or anything like that causing this issue? And how could I possibly fix it?
After a bit more testing, the program just seems to be running too long, and so my ide was suspending it. For large cases (but smaller than the test ones I provided here) it seems to run fine, it just takes a long time. i.e. it took 15 seconds when processing numbers from 1 to 1000. I need to get this runtime down to below 2 seconds when using the even larger numbers 1 to 1000000. So my actual question I suppose is how can I make this code more efficient?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct Team
{
    int solP; // Number of solved problems
    int numP; // Number of penalties
    int rank;
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0)); 
    vector<Team> teams; // 0 denotes team 1
    vector<int> favoriteTeam; // Filled with ranks of favorite team
    vector<int> rank; // Filled with ranks from last event
    int numTeams;
    int numEvents;

    //cin >> numTeams >> numEvents; // Read in line 1 // TEST TEST TEST
    numTeams = (rand() % (int)10e5) + 1;
    numEvents = (rand() % (int)10e5) + 1;
    teams.resize(numTeams);
    favoriteTeam.resize(numEvents);
    rank.resize(numTeams);
    for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
    {
        Team temp;
        temp.solP = 0;
        temp.numP = 0;
        temp.rank = 1;
        teams[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numEvents; i++)
    {
        int t, p;
        t = (rand() % numTeams) + 1;
        p = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
        ++teams[t - 1].solP;
        teams[t - 1].numP += p;

        // CALL FOR ORDER
        int modifier;
        int bestIndex;
        vector<bool> tie(numTeams);
        vector<bool> used(numTeams, false);

        // Sets up the rank vector
        for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
        {
            bestIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < numTeams; j++)
            {
                if (i == j || used[j]) continue;
                if (used[i] || teams[j].solP > teams[bestIndex].solP || teams[j].solP == teams[bestIndex].solP && teams[j].numP <= teams[bestIndex].numP)
                {
                    bestIndex = j;
                }
            }
            rank[i] = bestIndex;
            used[bestIndex] = true;
        }

        // Sets up the tie vector
        for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0 && teams[rank[i]].solP == teams[rank[i - 1]].solP && teams[rank[i]].numP == teams[rank[i - 1]].numP)
            {
                tie[i] = true;
            }
            else tie[i] = false;
        }

        // Sets the rank for each team
        modifier = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
        {
            if (tie[i]) modifier++;
            teams[rank[i]].rank = i + 1 - modifier;
        }

        // Set output
        favoriteTeam[i] = teams[0].rank;
    }

    //cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numEvents; i++)
    {
        cout << favoriteTeam[i] << endl;

    }

    cout << clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    return 0;
}


What is the largest input number for which the program doesn't get stuck?

Honestly I'm not sure how to test for that.

Run the program with different input numbers and see if it gets stuck or not.

OT: Whenever you feel the need to use a C-style explicit conversion (a cast, like what you do with (int)10e5) it should almost always be taken as a sign that you're probably are doing something wrong. Your case with rand is such a case. First of all it's not a good way to get values in a range. Secondly the RAND_MAX might be less than 100000. Thirdly 10e5 is a double value. And lastly C++ have much better random number generation than the old C function.

As for testing and debugging, don't rely on random values or user-input. Hard-code actual values into the code. Will make it much easier to see what might be going on. I also recommend you scale back your code to the absolute minimum (basically an empty main function). Then add a very small bit of code, perhaps just one single line. Build (with extra warnings enabled) and test. Only when it works you go on to add the next very small bit of code. When there's a problem it will be much easier to isolate it into a [mre] and debug it.

"gets stuck at runtime" is a situation that calls for a debugger. As a first order of business, split your program into problem generation and solution. The interface between the two should be a data structure close to the original input. For example a vector of pairs of ints.

This question is similar to: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I edited the question to better represent my issue. Unfortunately don't think this is an issue that a debugger will be able to solve, though please let me know if I am wrong about that.

To me it's very very odd that your IDE would suspend an application for running a few seconds. At work (research medical imaging) we have had applications that take several hours to process a single case (several GB in size) and we have not experienced any type of suspend problem with Visual Studio / msvc.

rand() % (int)10e5 is meaningless

Complexity of your solution is numEvents * numTeams^2, which in worst case when rand returning 32767 is 35,181,150,961,663 loops.

@assessedDavid Unfortunately don't think this is an issue that a debugger will be able to solve -- A debugger that has a "break all" or similar function that allows the debugger to halt the thread or process temporarily so you see where you are stuck will "solve" the problem.  If you have a debugger with this ability (Visual Studio does), then you may see that you are stuck in one of those loops that attempts trillions of iterations.

So my actual question I suppose is how can I make this code more efficient? -- That is like asking "how do I make a bubble sort more efficient?".  The answer to that is "use a different sort, not bubble sort".  So in your case it would be to devise a better algorithm, where the new algorithm/code may not look anything like what you're doing now.

and it works for smaller numbers such as their test input of: 3 4 2 7 3 5 1 6 1 9 -- And to that, you've stumbled into one of the tricks that the "competitive coding" sites do so well.  The questions on those sites almost always have a naive, easy to code, solution that works with small sets of numbers.  The problem is when the test sample is large, those naive, easy, solutions will never work.  The real aim of those questions is to see if you know the trick, algorithm, data structure(s), etc. to handle such large sets of numbers.  Obviously looping trillions of times is not a solution.

From reading the problem, I think you started out incorrectly.  Assume you have no idea the number of teams (the number of teams is really irrelevant) or even the number of events.  Assume you are just getting a steady stream of input until the input ends (the number of items should only be used to determine how many times to loop -- it shouldn't be used to resize vectors or similar).  To me, this boils down to maintaining statistics in an appropriate data structure and updating the data structure when a new (or already seen) team shows up with an answered question.

The question is missing some vital information, like what the program is supposed to do. Note the question should be self sufficient, so it should not be necessary to look up an external resource to understand it.

The issue you are facing is because of the difference in size between favoriteTeam and teams.
If numTeams is less than numEvents then you will have more favorite teams than the number of teams when you resize both teams and favoriteTeam.
